# Native Base toolbar not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Im attempting to follow the Native Base tutorial found in the docs.

https://nativebase.io/docs/v0.1.0/components

As soon as I try to add the toolbar I get the below error. The toolbar component does not seem to be in the package. Does anyone know if the documentation for Native Base is good?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Toolbar, Button, Text, Content, View } from 'native-base';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Toolbar></Toolbar>
        <Content>
          <View>
            <Text>Works! And some</Text>
          </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: After going to the github repo I found the latest docs. My Google search was bringing me to the old docs. Thanks anyways.

Comment: NativeBase is on 2.1.4 now. Check [Docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/) for it